# Facebook SDK/API for Mac OS X (not iOS)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, facebook-graph-api, sdk

How do I implement Facebook into a Mac OS X Application? Is there a Facebook SDK/API for Mac OS X (not iOS)?

I prefer to keep a *standalone* application and not require a back-end.